# Problem on selecting group of card from a well shuffled pack of card

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a problem I'm working on:

> The minimum number of cards to be dealt from an arbitrarily shuffled deck of 52 card to guarantee that three cards are from some same suit is which amount?

I got a few solutions using the pigeonhole principle, but I don't have a clear idea about this how to solve this problem correctly.

Comment: Tell us your solution! That way we can decide the best way to help you

Comment: pigeon hole principle states that "if n pigeons are assigned to m pigeon holes where n>>m than one pigeon hole must have        ((n-1)/m)+1 pigeons.  so m=4 and number of pigeon 3 so          (n-1)/4 +1=  3 and you get n=9.

Comment: Understand that this is not a statistics problem, since you have to *guarantee* an outcome.  Ie, you need to figure out the worst case.

Comment: If you have 5 cards on your hand you have, for sure, at least 2 of the same suit. Continue reasoning like this, this is the pigeon-hole principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although my math professor would hate me answering the question like this but, anyways...

Assume a standard $52$ card deck with no jokers. Then, we have four suits. And $13$ of each suit. Pick a card and let's  arbitrarily assume it's a club. So, now our "hand" contains $\lbrace club_1 \rbrace$.

Now, I may not choose from that suit again. Then, pick another card from a different suit. So, arbitrarily assume that I select a heart. And now our hand contains $\lbrace club_1, heart_1 \rbrace$.

Continue this process until we have one kind of each suit. Our hand contains $\lbrace club_1, heart_1, spade_1, diamond_1 \rbrace$. I can then pick four more cards, in the same fashion and have I still have less than three cards of the same suit. That is, my hand has  $\lbrace club_1, heart_1, spade_1, diamond_1, club_2, heart_2, spade_2, diamond_2 \rbrace$.

The next card I select must be from one of the four suits, and then I have made a hand which contains three suits of one kind.

On this note, the other answers are much more proper in their logic, and make excellent use of mathematical principles. But I hope this answer gives you a little more intuition on the reasoning behind the pigeon hole principle.

Comment: Thanks.Now i understand the concept.

Comment: Your math professor should approve of this answer, not hate it. It requires just enough abstraction to be convincing - not more.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** What is the maximum number of cards that can be dealt such that it is possible that there are not three cards from the same suit ?

If you have this answer, the answer to your question is the same, plus $1$.

Comment: Sorry i dont get it

Comment: If you deal $2$ cards from each suit, you have managed to deal $8$ cards without having $3$ of the same suit. So your answer is $>8$. If you deal another one, what happens ?

Answer (score 2):

Your comment

> pigeon hole principle states that "if n pigeons are assigned to m pigeon holes where n>>m than one pigeon hole must have ((n-1)/m)+1 pigeons. so m=4 and number of pigeon 3 so (n-1)/4 +1= 3 and you get n=9

gives the correct answer.

There are $4$ suits and $2 \lt 3$ so it is possible to have $4 \times 2=8$ cards without guaranteeing that three cards are from some same suit.  So $8$ cards are not enough.

However $8$ cards means all the *pigeonholes* are full and a $9$th card does guarantee that three cards are from some same suit.

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about this systematically, using a smaller example: suppose we want the minimum number of cards drawn such that there *must* be a repeat in one suit, and suppose we're talking about a regular deck with no jokers.

If you drew two cards, you could get repeat clubs- but it *doesn't have* to happen: you could draw a club and a heart, for example. Same with three cards.

Now, if you drew four cards, there doesn't have to be a repeat: you could have drawn a club, heart, spade, and diamond. What happens when we draw one more card, bringing your total count to 5? That set of a club, heart, spade, and diamond will be joined by one more of a club, heart, space, *or* diamond. We don't know which one, but by drawing 5, we guarantee that at least one of the suits will have a repeat.

So, the answer to that example is 5. Can you try the same for 3 cards being of the same suit, instead of 2? Try using the same logic I gave you.